# create expo proguard mapping files for google store over expo.dev

Tags: android, react-native, expo

The Google Store require the expo proguard mapping files, in old version which creates the native android projects the files where in this files, with latest expo version where everything goes over the cloud service this is not longer possible.

Im currently looking for a way to get this files back to submit the files to the google play console.

help with the config files when its maybe a problem with it